# How to  scroll down to particular child of a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

How to scroll down to a nth child of a div. Consider this code

```
 <span id="click_me">Click me to scroll down to nth child</span>
```

Messages div has 6 childs. I want to scroll down to 3rd or 4th child which somebody click on "click_me"

Note: Childs are added dynamically. Using some ajax functions calls/juggernaut push notifications.

```
<div class="messages" id="messages_212">
    <div class="message_container">
        <p><b>Sahil grover: </b>5</p> 
    <div>
    <div class="message_container">
        <p><b>Sahil grover: </b>4</p> 
    <div>
    <div class="message_container">
        <p><b>Sahil grover: </b>3</p> 
    <div>
    <div class="message_container">
        <p><b>Sahil grover: </b>2</p> 
    <div>
    <div class="message_container">
        <p><b>Sahil grover: </b>1</p> 
    <div>

    <div class="message_container">
        <p><b>Sahil grover: </b>0</p> 
    <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

plugin homepage and docs at: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

```
//scroll to nth child
var child = 3;
$.scrollTo($(".message_container")[child]);
```

or

```
//scroll to nth child
var child = 3;
$.scrollTo("#messages_212:nth-child("+child+")");
```

Comment: cant i use id instead of class for this?? I am getting an error in that case ie: targ is undefined
[Break On This Error] var val = targ[pos];

Comment: yep, `id` will work,  i didn't put it cause you didn't have any ids in there,  read the docs,  there are many options

Comment: are you trying to scroll to message_212,  or the nth child of message_212?  I edited my answer assuming the nth child because thats what your question asks

Answer (score 5):

I don't use jQuery (or any framework), but it's easy to do in plain JavaScript:

```
d = document.getElementById('messages_212');
d.scrollTop = d.children[2].offsetTop;
// children[2] for the third div, [3] for the fourth, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is jQuery plugin for that: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/